# Android app running in emulator but not in android device

Tags: android, android-emulator, samsung-mobile

I have tried for whole day fixing this problem with relevant research. I am able to run my application in emulator but not in android device ie samsung galaxy ace 2. I got following as error in logcat. Your help is really appreciated. Thank you!

```
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at com.dorji.finalproject.LoginLayout$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(LoginLayout.java:87)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at com.dorji.finalproject.LoginLayout$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(LoginLayout.java:1)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
03-20 18:40:07.340: E/AndroidRuntime(15785):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Main error code:

```
     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new newAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class newAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
        ProgressDialog Dialog;
        String user = username.getText().toString();
        String pass = password.getText().toString();



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
                Dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "processing..", "data is Loading...");
        }


        @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    if(res.equals("1")){
                        if (Dialog.isShowing()) {
                        Dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                } else{
                        error.setText("Sorry, wrong username and password");
                        Dialog.dismiss();
                }
                }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


             ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
             postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));

                String response = null;
                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/MainServer/LoginResponse", postParameters);
                    res=response.toString();
                    res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("param1", user);
                    bundle.putString("param2", pass);

                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.toString());
                            }
                        return null;
                        }
        }
```

Comment: I think what you need is a handler for the change in the display. The handler will allow you to modify any visual element on the screen. Maybe that could help you.

Comment: @jclandero23, can you please illustrate me bit more. I cant get you. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device can not access "10.0.2.2:8080" so you get into the exception and return null from doInBackground. 
In onPostExecute you try to run method equals() on null, and get a null pointer exception

Comment: Thank you very much but the thing is there is no problem with my emulator where it could access server. So can you suggest the url alternative to that one. I will try other as well

Comment: Only a guess: this IP is on an internal network, and your phone is not on the internal network. Maybe connect to the same wifi network as your desktop is

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: Can you please illustrate me this problem: 03-20 20:36:49.010: E/URL(24805): > http://10.0.2.2:8080/MainServer/register
03-20 20:36:58.310: E/Final Year Project(24805): Failed to register on attempt 2:java.net.ConnectException: 10.0.2.2/10.0.2.2:8080 - Network is unreachable

Comment: It means you can not reach the target address. Check that you have network access on your device (open a browser). Also 10.0.2.2 is an internal network address, not a public one, so make sure you are on an internal network that can access this IP

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but maybe this could help you:

1.- Add a handler:

```
private Handler myHndlr = null;
```

2.- Initialize it:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
       myHndlr = new Handler();
       //...
```

3.- Use it inside your AsyncTask:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        if(res.equals("1"))
        {
            myHndlr.post(new Runnable(){
               @Override
               public void run()
               {
                  //Code that modify items on the screen and stuff
                  if(Dialog.isShowing())
                  {
                       Dialog.dismiss();
                  }
               }
           });
         }
         //The rest of the code here...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Manifest, Change the target sdk (targetSdkVersion) corresponding to the version of your device's android version. It should work fine.

For example, API version of Android version 4.2.2 is API level 17. So, change the following in your Android Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```